# How to obtain the result of a chemical reaction given two components?

Tags: software-rec

For example, I enter "N2 + H2" and it gives me
"N<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>2</sub> → NH<sub>3</sub>".

Or "C10H8 + O2" and it shows "C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>8</sub> + O<sub>2</sub> → CO<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O".

I don't need coefficient calculator, where I type full reaction and it calculates coefficients (marked bold in next example):

C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>8</sub> + **12** O<sub>2</sub> = **10** CO<sub>2</sub> + **4** H<sub>2</sub>O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found, what I exactly need. [Nigma.ru](http://nigma.ru) can solve some of these chemical reactions. For example, if I type "N2 + H2", it gives me a result and it's type: N<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>2</sub> = N<sub>2</sub>H<sub>2</sub> (gas). Unfortunatly, it is russian. I'm russian, so for me it is ok :-) However, you can use Google Translate with this website to see it in english.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, [Google](http://www.google.com).

If somebody's put the result of the reaction on the net, google will know about it. Doing the reactions of any two elements accurately and definitively would basically require somebody to program a universe simulator, wheras we already have a perfectly good universe to test things out manually, right here.

edit: CW so people can downvote me, this answer really isn't deserving of a bounty, on the offchance to OP doesn't return in time.

Comment: I somehow expect Wolfram|Alpha to get better results, but I cannot find an example -- so maybe not. http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Chemistry.html

Comment: I tried use Wolfram Alpha, but it doesn't solve chemical reactions.

Comment: Google is good but it is inconvenient for these purposes (many irrelevant results) and it don't know some reactions that are rarely used in life but still possible. Authenticity of search results can also be prejudiced. However, only your response is answering my question.

Comment: @Semyon; It's the best answer I can think of, but it's really not my field, and it's not perfect. I just hope somebody else can come along with a better one :(

Answer (score 5):

Would this [**Chemical Equations Calculator**](http://www.trimen.pl/witek/calculators/wspolczynniki.html) do? If not, there is a lot of hits returned for the search "[chemical reaction calculator online](http://www.google.be/search?q=chemical+reaction+calculator+online)".

Answer (score 5):

Computational Chemistry -- that is, simulating the chemical reactions rather than simply having a database of reactants -- is well known as one of the classic supercomputer CPU sinks.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_chemistry) has an introduction, and Google will give the expected large number of links.

Answer (score 2):

Also see http://folding.stanford.edu/English/Science for interesting semi-related reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can try AcuraSoft's **[AcuraCHEM 2.0](http://www.acurasoft.com/products/acurachem2.php)**.

[image]

> The premier collection of chemical
>   utilities and tools designed and
>   developed by professional chemists to
>   fulfill the growing needs of chemists,
>   researchers, educators and students.
>   Chemists no longer need to waste
>   precious time on routine calculations
>   and may devote their valuable time on
>   productive activities.

Comment: Didn't find the way to get a result of any reaction. This tool mostly make some math calculating such as equation balancing, mass calculating etc.